# showing html in the browser but not the textbox

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux, material-ui

**update1**: updated image for better understanding

[image]

I am trying to implement chip filters similar to googleflights. Right now when you select sports it will show sports1 it will replace sports by sports1.

However, I wanted to insert a textbox, when I enter somevalue in the textbox and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> the primary fee schedule value should change to the entered value.

Can you tell me how to fix it?

chip related code is in chip-selector and tab-demo
since if I enter textbox tag. I am just getting string

[code snippet](https://www.google.fr/flights#flt=/m/0ggh3./m/02_286.2018-11-24*/m/02_286./m/0ggh3.2018-11-28;c:USD;e:1;s:0*0;sd:1;t:f) and [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/80wk4qzj9)

```
const primaryFeeMenuItems = [
   "primaryFeeMenuItems1",
   "<input type=\"text\" name=\"fname\">",
   "primaryFeeMenuItems2",
   "primaryFeeMenuItems3"
];

<td>
   <SimpleMenu
        buttonName="Primary Fee Schedule"
        menuItems={primaryFeeMenuItems}
   />
</td>
handleDelete() {
    this.setState({ display: !this.state.display });
 }

handleClick = event => {
    console.log("handle Click");
    this.setState({ anchorEl: event.currentTarget });
};

handleClose = e => {
    console.log(e.menuItem);
    if (e.menuItem) {
      this.setState({ display: !this.state.display });
      this.setState({ chipName: e.menuItem });
    }
    this.setState({ anchorEl: null });
};
```

Comment: Hey I tried and posted...can you please help...can you guys let me know how to remove negative marks

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: @SujilMaharjan hey thanks for your reply...I have updated the image where it shows chips menu...I am trying to achieve similar to that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `Menu` which works a little differently than what you are trying to achieve. Actually looking into how Google Flights is using these filters, it seems like they are using `Chips` and `Dialog` components to produce that result. Once you use a `Dialog` component, you can define the content yourself.

[I have created a sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vmqyjz2xx7)

I converted your code to take Dialog instead of Menu.

```
<div>
        <Chip
          style={{ display: this.state.display ? "" : "none" }}
          label={this.state.chipName}
          onDelete={this.handleDelete}
          className={this.props.classes.chip}
          color="primary"
        />

        <Button
          style={{ display: this.state.display ? "none" : "" }}
          aria-owns={anchorEl ? "simple-menu" : undefined}
          aria-haspopup="true"
          onClick={this.handleClick}
        >
          {this.props.buttonName}
        </Button>

        <Dialog
          onClose={this.handleClose}
          aria-labelledby="simple-dialog-title"
          open={this.state.openDialog}
        >
          <DialogTitle id="simple-dialog-title" style={titleStyle}>
            Set backup account
          </DialogTitle>
          <div>
            <input type="text" placeHolder="type here" />
            <List>{menuItems}</List>
          </div>
        </Dialog>
      </div>
```

`menuItems` returns ListItem instead of MenuItems. Find the full code in the sandbox.

The `input` you are trying to get should be before the `List`. You can handle that any way you want.

I haven't overridden the CSS properties for Dialog. So, once you override the backdrop background color and position of the dialog, you should achieve the display as well.

Comment: can you help me with this one --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53232921/implementing-footer-in-the-advanced-search-tab-drawer/53233042?noredirect=1#comment93353520_53233042