# capitalize the first letter in a word for a normal state

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

- I am trying to overwrite the material UI css.
- I tried to capitalize both the words, but its changing only on selected and hover,
- is it possible to change it in normal state too
- I debugged but not able to fid the issue.
- can you tell me how to fix it.
- providing my code snippet below and sandbox below.

https://codesandbox.io/s/2pomwq2z20

```
const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    width: "100%",
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper
  },
  tabsIndicator: {
    backgroundColor: "red",
    textTransform: "capitalize"
  },
  tabRoot: {
    "&:hover": {
      color: "red",
      opacity: 1,
      textTransform: "capitalize"
    },
    "&$tabSelected": {
      color: "red",
      fontWeight: theme.typography.fontWeightMedium,
      textTransform: "capitalize"
    },
    "&:focus": {
      color: "red",
      textTransform: "capitalize"
    }
  },
  tabSelected: {}
});
```

Comment: Have you tried `tabRoot: { textTransform: "capitalize", ... }`?

Comment: @tholle thanks for your reply...I updated but still it doesn't work :( providing updated code here https://codesandbox.io/s/2pomwq2z20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `textTransform: "initial"` in tabRoot. Look into https://codesandbox.io/s/p5z9m029v0

Comment: hey first letter alone I should show in Caps for both search and favorites tex

Comment: hey it worked...can you tell me why you added in tabRoot, so that in future I will fix it myself

Comment: It is because of the text in the tab by default looks into tabRoot's CSS properties. So, when we transformed the text inside tabRoot, that css property was picked up.

Comment: hey thanks so much, can you help me with this...not sure how to proceed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53215128/showing-html-in-the-browser-but-not-the-textbox

Comment: hey can you help me with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53265169/css-position-absolute-making-the-tetxbox-go-down