# implementing footer in the advanced search tab drawer

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to develop a sticky footer similar to w3schools.

I used the same code in my material UI demo, but it is not working.

I debugged and changed `position` from `fixed` to `absolute`, but it still doesn't work. Can you guys help me? Is it due to material ui or is it due to display block?

When you click the advanced search tab, you can see the red color footer in the drawer. Providing my code snippet and sandbox below:

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_fixed_footer

https://codesandbox.io/s/jvmoj49w1y

```
footer: {
    position: "fixed",
    left: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    width: 100,
    backgroundColor: "red",
    color: "white",
    textAlign: "center"
}

<div className={classes.footer}>
   <p>Footer</p>
</div
```

Comment: Should this footer occupy the full width?

Comment: @SujilMaharjan yes

Comment: @SujilMaharjan can you help me

Answer (score 0):

The element above your footer is causing the screen height to increase. 
You need to make the position of the footer relative to that element, so it is always below it.

```
position: "relative",
```

Comment: hey I updated but if I change the position, it changes the footer goes down and I am able to see it only after I scroll, is it possible to see the footer without scrolling

Comment: I can't seem to access your code sandbox anymore as it freezes. But Footers generally appear at the bottom of the screen, if you don't want to scroll you need to reduce the height of the element above the footer. Or wrap the element in a container that has it's own scroll bar.

Comment: it should be similar to the stackoverflow search nav bar, when you scroll down it doent move but the content goes beneath it